# TypeError: chart_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not a function

Tags: angular, intro.js

I'm trying to install intro.js in Angular and work on it but encountered an issue showing

```
TypeError: intro_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not a function
    at new AppComponent (app.component.ts:12:13)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.AppComponent_Factory [as factory] (app.component.ts:44:4)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.js:3549:1)
    at instantiateRootComponent (core.js:10116:1)
    at createRootComponent (core.js:12475:1)
    at ComponentFactory$1.create (core.js:25137:1)
    at ApplicationRef.bootstrap (core.js:29608:1)
    at core.js:29321:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at PlatformRef._moduleDoBootstrap (core.js:29321:1)
```

Steps I took to install intro.js are

1. npm install intro.js @types/intro.js --save
2. Open angular.json and

   "styles": [
   "src/styles.scss",
   "node_modules/intro.js/introjs.css"
   ],
   "scripts": [
   "node_modules/intro.js/intro.js"
   ],
3. Import Intro.js to your app.component.ts at the top of your file
4. Added code

   @Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
   })
   export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   introJS = introJs();

   constructor(public authService: AuthServiceService) {
   this.introJS.setOptions({
   steps: [
   {
   element: '#step1',
   intro: 'Welcome to your new app!',
   position: 'bottom'
   },
   {
   element: '#step2',
   intro: "Ok, wasn't that fun?",
   position: 'right'
   },
   {
   element: '#step3',
   intro: "let's keep going",
   position: 'top'
   },
   {
   element: '#step4',
   intro: 'More features, more fun.',
   position: 'right'
   }
   ],
   showProgress: true
   });
   }

   ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   this.introJS.start();
   }
   }

Comment: it looks like introJS is not a function. Could you do console.log(introJS) and see what it has

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you default `import` and not via `*`.

You might need to add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to your `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`.